# Core Data -Crash on certain Properties: objc_release

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have several properties inside my CoreData Entity file named *UnsavedModel*, here are some of them.

[image]

I created my own file with a CollectionView and when I instantiate the `newBodyText` and `newHttpsStr` properties, it crashes. The correct values are being fed into both of the properties, which are just Strings, but it only crashes on those properties, none of the other properties. **If I don't give those properties a value, everything works fine**. What's the issue here?

The problem occurs in this order:

1. HomeVC > buttonPress immediately push on UnsavedVC
2. UnsavedVC (cells correctly load) > backButtonPressed immediately pop back to HomeVC
3. HomeVC > buttonPress immediately push on UnsavedVC
4. CRASH

FYI I have no problems writing to those properties. But when I do try to delete those 2 properties, it crashes, but have no problem deleting any of the other properties.

I've also gotten a crash on `Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)` for the same issue.

[image]

code:

```
class UnsavedController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var datasource = [CopyCoreDataModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() {

        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        // I also tried context.performAndWait { ... run the do-try-catch fetchRequest in here... }

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<UnsavedModel> = UnsavedModel.fetchRequest()

        do {
            let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            for result in results {
                
                guard let id = result.value(forKey: "id") as? String else { continue }
                
                let isContained = tableData.contains(where: { $0.id ?? "" == id })
                
                if !isContained {
                    let copy = CopyCoreDataModel(id: id, unsavedModel: result)
                    datasource.append(copy)
                }
            }
            
            collectionView.reloadData()

        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}

// CopyCoreDataModel is necessary because I run some functions based on certain properties
class CopyCoreDataModel {

    var fileUrl: URL?

    var id: String?
    var unsavedModel: UnsavedModel?

    var postDate: Double?
    // otherProperties of type String, Double, and Boolean

    var micUrl: String?
    var newBodyText: String?
    var newHttpsStr: String?

    init(id: String, unsavedModel: UnsavedModel) {

        self.id = id
        self.unsavedModel = unsavedModel

        // self otherProperties = unsavedModel.otherProperties // run some function on some of the other properties. These all work perfectly fine

        if let micUrl = unsavedModel.micUrl { // works perfectly fine
            self.micUrl = micUrl
            // function to get micURL from FileManager that eventually sets self.fileUrl
        }

        if let newBodyText = unsavedModel.newBodyText { // crash occurs here only if it has a value
            self.newBodyText = newBodyText
        }

        if let newHttpsStr = unsavedModel.newHttpsStr { // crash occurs here only if it has a value
            self.newHttpsStr = newHttspStr
        }
    }
}

func writeData(micURL: URL) {

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let entity: NSEntityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "UnsavedModel", in: context)!

    let object: NSManagedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    object.setValue(UUID().uuidString, forKey: "id")
    object.setValue(micURL.path, forKey: "micUrl")
    object.setValue("abc", forKey: "newBodyText")
    object.setValue("https...", forKey: "newHttpsStr")
    // set other properties

    do {
        try context.save()
        
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("could not save . \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

I also setup a sharedInstance like [this](https://medium.com/@maddy.lucky4u/swift-4-core-data-part-3-creating-a-singleton-core-data-refactoring-insert-update-delete-9811af2fcf75) and accessed the context through there `let context = CoreDataManager.sharedManager.persistentContainer.viewContext` but the same issue occurs

**UPDATE**

I also changed the CopyCoreDataModel's initializer to use a dict of the k/v from the unsavedModel but the crash still occurs

```
class CopyCoreDataModel {

    // same exact properties

    init(id: String, dict: [String: Any]) {

        // set the properties using the values from the dict

    }
}

func fetchData() {

    let context = // ...        
    let fetchRequest = // ...

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        for result in results {
            
            guard let id = result.value(forKey: "id") as? String else { continue }
            
            let isContained = datasource.contains(where: { $0.id ?? "" == id })
            
            if !isContained {
                
                let dict = createDictFromUnsavedModel(unsavedModel: result)
                let copy = CopyCoreDataModel(id: id, dict: dict)
                datasource.append(copy)
            }
        }
        
        collectionView.reloadData()

    } catch { 
    }
}

func createDictFromUnsavedModel(unsavedModel: UnsavedModel) -> [String:Any] {

    var dict = [String: Any]()

    // set dict using k/v from unsavedModel

    return dict
}
```

Comment: Probably unrelated, but isn't it supposed to be `self.newHttspStr = newHttspStr` rather than `self.newBodyText = newHttspStr`?

Comment: Oh yeah, that’s a typo on here, I don’t have that in my actual code (it’s correct). Let me fix it. Thanks! I think I just found the issue. I’m testing it and about to post now. The fix that I thought fixed it didn't fix it

Comment: @vadian I think you should check this answer out below. I know you're highly skilled in this, but this was a very easy thing to overlook. Maybe you'll come across this again. Thanks for your help btw!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, who would've thought ...

The issue was both names began with `new` as in **newBodyText** and **newHttpsStr**. That's not allowed in Obj-C and CoreData is based on Obj-C. I found the answer [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/397168/cfstring-release-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance) by @Silfverstrom

From Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/introduction/introduction.html):

> To allow interoperation with manual retain-release code, ARC imposes a
> constraint on method naming:
>
> You **cannot** give an accessor a **name** that begins with **new**. This in turn
> means that you **can’t**, for example, declare a **property** whose **name**
> **begins with new** unless you specify a different getter

Once I changed them from **newBodyText** and **newHttpsStr** to **updatedBodyText** and **updatedHttpsStr** the crash went away.